# while loop preventing Java JSSC serial port thread from reading/updating data

Tags: multithreading, loops, while-loop

I have a serial port thread running in the background.  I send a command to a device that takes time to return serial port data (10 seconds max).  I have a while loop running with a timeout waiting for the response I am looking for to update a variable I access with getReceivedData().  The data is never updated.  If I exit the loop I can get the data.  Any suggestions?  I am trying to exit the while loop once the data is detected and not just sit for a specific amount of time then check the data.

```
enter code here
```

public class SerialPorts extends Thread {

```
static volatile boolean EXIT=false;
public static volatile String RESPONSE="";
```

volatile String received="";

```
 byte[] r;
 String rdata="";
 String port;
 private static final AtomicReference<String> receivedData = new AtomicReference<>("");
 public static volatile String CMD="";
private final  SerialPort serialPort;
private  String portName;





public SerialPorts(String portName) {
    this.portName = portName;
    this.serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        serialPort.openPort();
        serialPort.setParams(
                SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE
        );

        serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialPortEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
                if (event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
                    try {
                        received = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                        appendToReceivedData(received);
                        System.out.println("Received data: " + received);
                        synchronized(Arduino_DMM.ob) {
                            Arduino_DMM.ob.notify();
                        }
                            
                    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Keep the serial port thread running
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            // Do nothing, let the listener handle incoming data
        }
    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            serialPort.closePort();
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void appendToReceivedData(String data) {
    // Using AtomicReference to ensure atomicity for thread safety
    receivedData.updateAndGet(currentData -> currentData + data);
}

public String getReceivedData() {
    String x= receivedData.get();
    receivedData.equals(null);
    return x;
}

public void SendCmd(String data) {
    try {
        serialPort.writeString(data);
        System.out.println("Transmitted data: " + data);
    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```